# Watermark for an ASP.Net Panel

Tags: asp.net, css

Does an asp.net panel can be inserted with a watermark? These panel is used for printing purposes. Another problem is that the background image in the panel is not printing, only the objects inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at `BackImageUrl` property. And assign the path of the watermark image to it.

```
<asp:Panel BackImageUrl="yourimagefile.png" />
```

Also, the image should be given a proper opacity / alpha value so that it's transparent.

Comment: I already tried it but it's not working. Same in a div also.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/ASPImaging1.aspx from codeproject that you can do many thinks on the image, including adding watermark from image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">

<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/yourimage.png" />

<div style="margin-top: -xxx"><--change the position <div> to overlaps with the image
....

your content here 

....
</div>

</asp:Panel>
```